# How do I load a section of config into a custom object using HostBuilder in an Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm trying to work out what I'm missing in this snippet of code.  I'm creating an Azure WebJob that I'm hoping to deploy to Azure, but I need to load a section of JSON from my `appsettings.json` file into a customer object I have created.  I don't seem to have the `GetSection` method available on the `builder` object and I don't understand what I'm missing so that I can map a section of config to my `HostOptions` class (the POCO taking the config section).

Here's my code, I am using .NET Core 3.0.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebJobs(config =>
        {
            config.AddTimers();
            config.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
            config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builderContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Some IoC mappings...
        })
        .Build();

    builder.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the overload for [`IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder.configureservices?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_WebHostBuilder_ConfigureServices_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_WebHostBuilderContext_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection__)

```
   .ConfigureServices((builderContext, services) => {
        IConfiguration configuration = builderContext.Configuration;
        HostOptions options = configuration.GetSection("MySection").Get<HostOptions>();

        services.AddSingleton(options);

        // Some IoC mappings...
    })
```